# How to use default argument when using generics

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-cant-i-write-typeof-t-new-t-or-instanceof-t-in-my-generic-function

I saw this FAQ in document, but I can't solve use case following below.

```js
class Foo {
  constructor() {}
}

function foo<T extends Foo> (
  fooClass: {new(): T} = Foo
                       ^^^^^^ 
                       recognized Type of Foo
) {
  const instance = new fooClass()
  // do more stuff...
}
```

Usecase to need  using generics is below.

```js
class Foo {
  a = 1
}

class Bar extends Foo {
  b = 1
}

class A {
  fooClass: {new(): Foo}
  constructor(fooClass: {new(): Foo} = Foo) {
    this.fooClass = fooClass
  }
  a () {
    return new this.fooClass()
  }
}

const instanceA = new A(Bar);
instanceA.a().b // => error
```

I want pass like this.

```js
class Foo {
  a = 1
}

class Bar extends Foo {
  b = 1
}

class A<FooClass extends Foo> {
  fooClass: {new(): FooClass }
  constructor(fooClass: {new(): FooClass} = Foo) { // => default value Foo is error
    this.fooClass = fooClass
  }
  a (): FooClass {
    return new this.fooClass()
  }
}

const instanceA = new A<Bar>(Bar);
instanceA.a().b
```

Could you tell me solutions if you know.

Comment: You cannot do that when you're using generics: in cases when `T extends Foo` but is not exactly `Foo` the `fooClass: Foo` assignment would be violating type check. Eg: `class Bar extends Foo { public s: string = '123'; } foo<Bar>();`

Comment: Do you really need generics? Wouldn't `function foo (
  fooClass: {new(): Foo} = Foo
                       
) {` do for you?

Comment: I can't understand why it is possible to assign Foo in calling function.

What is the difference `foo(Foo)` and `fooClass: {new(): T} = Foo`？

Comment: It's not clear: "What is the difference" --- one is a function call, the other is an argument with a default value declaration.

Comment: I need generics because I will make `Bar extends Foo` class, and use `function foo`.

Comment: Well, the question is missing some crucial details then: as it is asked now it does not require generics and I provided a solution without generics.

Comment: I understood your comments, your way can set default value just `foo(Bar)` (without generics), and it will satisfy my usecase. Thanks.

Comment: Does [this](https://tsplay.dev/WPxVEW) clear things up?  You can't assume that `Foo` will be of type `new() => T` because `T` is specified by the *caller*; if the caller wants to call `foo<Bar>()` then the implementation of `foo` will be pretending that `Foo` is a `Bar` constructor, which it isn't.  You can just not worry about it and use a type assertion, or you can do something like overloads to prevent invalid calls.  Does that meet your needs? If so I can write up an answer; if not please let me know what I'm missing.

Comment: I couldn't understand overloads behavior. Just not using generics, it was OK. Thanks.

Comment: I found a usecase to need generics, I added it.

Comment: How much do you care about someone writing `new A<Bar>().a().b.toFixed()` and fooling the compiler?  Either way, you could turn the assertion/overloads solutions into something that works here too, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WoJylm).  I don't know what to say about your inability to understand [overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) and their behavior; I'd be happy to explain in an answer, but right now I don't know if it meets your needs or not.